# Произвольный цвет фона и рамки для TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Как мне из такого поля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделать такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменить цвет несложно

```
this.textBox1.BackColor = Color.Black
```

или добавьте любой цвет через метод [`Color.FromArgb`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557(v=vs.110).aspx).

А вот регулировать цвет рамки придётся

1. Либо через написание собственного элемента управления (наследуемся от `UserControl` и добавляем обработчик для события `Paint`).
2. Либо через какие-то хаки вроде такого

   - оборачиваем наш `TextBox`в `Panel`
   - устанавливаем цвет фона `Panel` в нужный цвет.
   - убираем границы по умолчанию для `TextBox`
      `textBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;`